# css transition - issue when hovering on the element

Tags: css, css-transitions

Here's the snippet of my transition on my card component. I have a transition when it's being hovered on the box-shadow. It seems smooth when it is being hovered out but not when it's being hovered in (seems a bit sharp).

What did I miss in my css?

Here's my fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/zxfb981r/

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 7.75rem;
  transition: all 300ms;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(224, 224, 224, 0.5);
  border: solid 1px #F5F5F5;
}
.wrapper:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 2px 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.imageContainer {
  flex: 0 0 33%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 1.1825rem;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 0 0.25rem 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.price {
  color: #BAA082;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 2rem 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@media(min-width: 46.5rem) {
  .wrapper {
    height: 8.75rem;
  }
  .title {
    font-size: 1.1875rem;
  }
  .price {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <h4 class="title">Point of sale</h4>
    <p>Point of sale</p>
    <p class="price">From £165</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imageContainer">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556742521-9713bf272865?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=2134&amp;q=80" alt="" class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by sharp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `opacity` from `transition` will give you desire result. check snippet.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 7.75rem;
  transition: all 300ms;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(224, 224, 224, 0.5);
  border: solid 1px #F5F5F5;
}
.wrapper:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 2px 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.imageContainer {
  flex: 0 0 33%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 1.1825rem;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 0 0.25rem 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.price {
  color: #BAA082;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 2rem 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@media(min-width: 46.5rem) {
  .wrapper {
    height: 8.75rem;
  }
  .title {
    font-size: 1.1875rem;
  }
  .price {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <h4 class="title">Point of sale</h4>
    <p>Point of sale</p>
    <p class="price">From £165</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imageContainer">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556742521-9713bf272865?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=2134&amp;q=80" alt="" class="image"></div>
</div>
```